# Перенаправление на другой домен без смены адреса

Tags: apache, https, redirect

Есть некая CMS, которую не хотелось бы отдавать пользователю, а хранить сайты всех пользователей на моём хостинге. Но что бы пользователи могли использовать свои доменные имена.

К примеру у пользователя есть свой домен *userdomen.com*

Адрес сайта, которым должен управлять пользователь на моём хостинге – *[somehash].mydomen.com*

В Apache есть настройка, чтобы перебрасывать все запросы на другой домен без смены адреса в строке браузера. Собственно вопросы:

Всегда ли можно будет настроить такую переброску, не зависимо от того, где зарегистрирован домен пользователя? Какие могут быть минусы такого подхода? Сильно ли теряется в скорости? И как оно сотрудничает с https?

Comment: Для начала покажите вашу "настройку" а Apache.

Comment: У меня ещё нет никаких настроек. Я в общем хотел бы узнать как это правильно сделать. На локальном OpenServer получилось. Просто добавил в алиасы перенаправление с одного локального домена на другой.

Comment: Если вы настроили, и оно работает, в чем, собственно, вопрос? Скорость зависит только от пропускной способности вашего сервера. Вы должны понимать, если пользователь идет к вам на сервер, а ваш сервер проксирует запрос на какой-то другой сервер, то время отклика будет = время отклика вашего сервера + время отклика стороннего сервера.